# Java SplashScreen in Java Web Start

Tags: java, swing, maven, jnlp, splash-screen

I am trying to move my Java Swing project to Java Web Start
and I have problem with the splash screen. This application uses Maven.

When I load my application via the command-line or by an external exe, 
it displays the splash screen correctly.

```
final SplashScreen splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();
```

When I run application via Java Web Start, it always return `null`.

Yes, I know about splash screen section in JNLP file.

```
<icon kind="splash" href="splash.png"/>
```

But this will show splash screen before the application is loaded and not
when the application is running.  In other words, it isn't a replacement for the `--splash` switch.

In the manifest file, I have:

```
   SplashScreen-Image: (URL to resource,  file in jar)
```

This works well only when I run jar file and not in Java Web Start.

Has anybody had this same problem and found any solution for this?
I need a splash screen because the application takes several seconds to start and nothing is displayed for user in this time.

Answer (score 2):

To show a splash screen for JNLP clients, call the `start()` method passing the splash image path.  To remove the splash screen, call the `stop()` method.

```
public class ShowSplash 
{
   private static JWindow splashFrame;

   public void start(String splashImagePath) throws Exception
   {
      JLabel label;
      ImageIcon image;
      URL url;

      splashFrame = new JWindow();
      url         = ShowSplash.class.getResource(splashImagePath);
      image       = new ImageIcon(url);
      label       = new JLabel(image);

      splashFrame.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      splashFrame.pack();
      splashFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      splashFrame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public void stop() throws Exception
   {
      splashFrame.dispose();

      splashFrame = null;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The JWS based splash screen uses totally different functionality (and a different loading philosophy) to the AWT based `SplashScreen`.  The JWS splash is always a loose file that is referenced in the JNLP file.  We cannot get access to draw on the JNLP splash.

Comment: Yes, but I thought that in Java Web Start exists any substitute for --splash switch or manifest entry SplashScreen-Image.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers, but I have problem with replace SplashRenderer with JWindow.

Here is code:

```
    splashFrame = new JWindow();

    splashFrame.setBackground(Color.white);

    JPanel splashPanel = new JPanel();

    splashPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JLabel image = new JLabel(img);

    splashPanel.add(image); 

    splashFrame.setContentPane(splashPanel);
    splashFrame.pack();
    splashFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    splashFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    splashPanel.paintImmediately(0, 0, splashPanel.getSize().width, splashPanel.getSize().height);
    splashFrame.setSize(splashPanel.getSize().width,splashPanel.getSize().height);
    splashFrame.setLocation(100, 100);
    splashFrame.setVisible(true);
```

The Window is always in back, no metter if I set setAlwyasOnTop or if I set this methods
in background thread. SplashRender in this case always stays on top, but JWindow not.

Currently effect is - When I start APP the Window is not visible during start up, but it's shows when MainFrame appear.